# Simple PHP page to use Python not working

Tags: python, php, apache

Thanks for your time.
I took a new VPS, just to put online a software I'm developing. The VPS is on CentOs 7. I've installed HTTPD and PHP, Python was already installed. The index page is online.
I've found a sample at [cyberwarzone](https://cyberwarzone.com/send-php-data-to-python-and-back/) and I've created an **index.php** page like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="NAME"><br>
<input type="submit" value="NAME">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $param1 = $_POST["NAME"];    
    $command = escapeshellcmd("/var/www/html/cyberwarzone.py $param1 ");
    $resultAsString = shell_exec($command);
    echo $resultAsString;
?>
```

And a **cyberwarzone.py** file like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
workvalue = sys.argv[1]
workvalue = workvalue + '\t' + "Hello World, send from Cyberwarzone.py"
print(workvalue)
```

Now, when I enter any data, nothing happens. Python is in /usr/bin/python and html files are in /var/www/html/. Can anybody help me to troubleshoot it?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't escape the full command, escape the input only. `$command ='/var/www/html/cyberwarzone.py ';` and then `$resultAsString = shell_exec($command .  escapeshellcmd($param1));`  I think will be closer. This also assumes PHP user has permission to execute python commands, and shell access.

Comment: Thanks. But, this way, it always prints the string "$param1)"..

Comment: Prints that where? It only has one `)` as well? If you view page source is the full PHP script present?

Comment: I also tried setting all the content of /var/www/html 777 apache|apache. Nothing

Comment: Not clear what that's referencing/replying to.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. I was saving the .py file with windows EOL. Changing them, in NP++, resolved the problem. Thanks for your time